# Is it possible to set up a smart contract with multiple .cpp and .hpp files?

Tags: smart-contract, c++, compilation

If we want to make our smart contract code modular, and keep each class, contract, and table in its own file, is it possible to do this, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible:

1. Set up a new smart contract environment using `eosio-init`:

`eosio-init -project=mycontract -path=.`

2. Create all of your .cpp and .hpp files as appropriate
3. In the ./src folder, edit the `CMakeLists.txt` file by adding all of the `.cpp` files to the `add_contract` command, making sure that the file containing your contract class is the last file in the list:

`add_contract( mycontract mycontract table.cpp helper.cpp mycontract.cpp )`

4. If you have a table in its own file, and it isn't a member of the contract class, then it will not be included in the ABI file unless you indicate that it needs to be included in the contract in your attributes:

`class [[eosio::table, eosio::contract("mycontract")]] mytable`